# Sonoma 14.1.1 - Dyalog APL installer fails with "Trust evaluate failure"

Tags: install

I'm trying to install a software package (Dyalog APL) that I've installed successfully on many occasions before, but suddenly the installer fails -- or rather, it appears to go through the motions (installer claims to have been successful), but nothing appears in the /Applications folder.

Looking at the logs, I see the following error messages:

```
Trust evaluate failure: [leaf ExtendedKeyUsage] [ca1 Intermediate EKU]
```

Any ideas if this is related, and if so, what can be done to fix it? It seems to be a problem on my machine, as others on the same or similar hardware and OS version don't appear to have this problem.

M2 Pro, Sonoma 14.1.1